# If using one DbContext instance per request, should I dispose the context on each request as well:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented a base controller that instantiates a new `DbContext` per request:

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected HawkHeadDbContext Db { get; set; }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        Db = new HawkHeadDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        Db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am just a little worried that the `Dispose` call could become CPU intensive, and maybe I should dispose the context in the `Dispose` method of `BaseController`. I suspect the controller is instantiated for each request, but not sure if `Dispose` is called after each request, or in a regular 'DisposeAllControllers' type operation.

Comment: "When working with Web applications, use **a context instance per request.**" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am using one instance per request. What do you think the `Db = new HawkHeadDbContext();` does in `OnActionExecuting`? I'm not asking about that, but about when to dispose the context, as doing so may extend the time of the request. I may not dispose in `OnActionExecuted`, but then will have a growing collection of un-disposed but un-used contexts that I may dispose in some other, maybe batched, means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context is designed for short time lifetime. Usually you see it in

```
using(var ctx = new DbContext())
{
    ...
}
```

Which means ctx.Dispose is called just after end of use.

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx), see "lifetime" section.

So regarding your code, if you aren't using dependency injection (In which case you would have configured dbcontext as per request) you are doing well disposing it after action execution.

The only concern would be what if you call child actions.. In that case you may end having more than one dbcontext per request

Comment: So maybe I should check if it is a child action and skip creating a new context. I don't know if it's by default possible to check, but I could mark child actions with an attribute, if not already the built in `ChildActionOnly` attribute. I will only much later be using DI, then I'll let it take care of disposing.